# Looking for 80s/90s YA Horror Story Compilation

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I have been trying to find this collection for a while now; this is the first forum i've asked in.

It was probably a short book, with stories in the style of Christopher Pike and R.L. Stine. I only remember two of the stories.

1.) A girl goes out with her parents--camping or shopping or something--and meets a strange girl around her age who has a t-shirt with two lips on it. She becomes friends with the girl and stuff happens (sorry, i don't remember!), and in the end, the girl has somehow taken her place in her home, and she looks down at herself and sees she is wearing the t-shirt with lips on it, and has to wander alone now.

2.) A boy runs away from home because he's mad at his mom, and is taken up by a nice motherly lady, who tricks him into entering her house, then locks him in her basement, where he is alone in the dark, above a trapdoor. In the trapdoor is something that eats him, as the ending is implied.

Thanks for any help you can give! It's weird, but I want so much to remember these!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it *could* be one of the [Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark) books. I remember them being aimed at a slightly younger age group than YA, despite the chilling illustrations (they were later re-released with much tamer pictures).